# C Programming-how to set output picture file to .pgm format?

Tags: c

Instead of asking user to enter output name I need the program to automatically create it as out1.pgm.  How can do I it?

```
       {
        printf("Enter image filename: ");
        scanf("%s", fileName);

        img = readpic(fileName);

        printf("Successfully read image file '%s'\n", fileName);
        printf("Adjust brightness: ");
        scanf("%d", &brightness);

        option1(img, brightness);

        printf("Enter image filename for output: ");
        scanf("%s", fileName);

        writeoutpic(fileName,img);



        free(img);
        img = NULL;
        return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `scanf("%s", fileName);` to `strcpy(fileName, "out1.pgm");`